# Reactjs axios send request somany time

Tags: reactjs

I get a local token and request to get user information for my Navbar, but my Axios function send request so many time ( up to 12 times ) and I don't know why :
[image]

This is my code:

```
const history = useHistory()
const [username, setUsername] = useState([''])
const localToken = localStorage.getItem('authToken')
axios.get('https://my-gs-server.herokuapp.com/api/posts/user/info',
    {
        headers: {
            authToken: localToken
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
            setUsername(res.data.username)
            console.log(res.data)
        }
        else {
            localStorage.removeItem('authToken')
        }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('authToken')
    history.push('/login')
    window.location.reload();
}
```

my navbar :

```
 <Navbar>
<Navbar.Collapse className='my-nav-collapse flex-column' id="navbarScroll">
                            <Nav navbarScroll className="mt-4 mb-4 ml-auto my-2 my-lg-0 my-Nav align-items-center d-flex justify-content-start">
                                {
                                    localStorage.getItem('authToken') ?
                                        <>
                                            <NavDropdown bsPrefix='nav-dropdown' title={username} id="navbarScrollingDropdown">
                                                <NavDropdown.Item onClick={logout}>Logout</NavDropdown.Item>
                                            </NavDropdown>
                                        </>
                                        :
                                        <>
                                            <Nav.Link bsPrefix='my-nav-signup-link' href="/register">logout</Nav.Link>
                                            <Nav.Link bsPrefix='my-nav-login-link' href="/login">login</Nav.Link>
                                        </>
                                }
                            </Nav>
                        </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
```

Comment: Because you make the request every time the component renders, which updates the state, which re-renders the component, which makes the request again, which ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` hook is what you looking for to trigger api calls when component mounts

```html
const history = useHistory()
const [username, setUsername] = useState([''])
const localToken = localStorage.getItem('authToken')

React.useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://my-gs-server.herokuapp.com/api/posts/user/info',
    {
        headers: {
            authToken: localToken
        }
    })
    .then((res) => {
        if (res.status == 200) {
            setUsername(res.data.username)
            console.log(res.data)
        }
        else {
            localStorage.removeItem('authToken')
        }
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('authToken')
    history.push('/login')
    window.location.reload();
}
```